# How can I run inkscape being installed as a snap package?

Tags: snap, inkscape

I installed [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/linux/) by using the following command:

```
sudo snap install inkscape
```

It is installed correctly, however it is not shown in the application menu.

```
$ snap list
inkscape
version : 0.92.0 
Rev : 1879
Developer : inkscape
```

How can I run inkscape ?

Comment: just run `inkscape` in terminal and I would think its also available in `dash`.

Comment: No it is not working!

Comment: After switching it to gnome it is working perfectly. But it is not working with unity

Comment: works fine here in ubuntu session, inkscape command works & resultant icon in launcher can be pinned. Make sure you have latest snapd package. If desired try navigating to `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`. Inside should be a file named Inkscape. Drag & drop it on the unity launcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say "After switching to GNOME it is working perfectly. But it is not working with Unity." :

In Ubuntu with Unity desktop environment open a terminal and execute : `/snap/bin/inkscape`

This is the same with other `snap` packages having missing launchers : `/snap/bin/<snap-name>`